# How to disable this feature in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried turning off Code lens but this wont turn off, How do i get rid of this feature its
quite annoying.

steps to reproduce

- Press the combination Alt+Shift+R on any code block to refactor it and create a method
- This window appears on top or bottom based on scrolling position
  *note that the class was approx 1000 lines

Restarting Android Studio gets rid of this for once but it appears again next time I run above steps.

attaching screenshot for ref (check the top area) [image: check the floating windows above]

Answer (score 0):

Please uncheck the code lens. it might be helpful for you.

[image]

Comment: I wrote in the first line of question that i disabled code lens but it doesnt work

Comment: I think it's produced in your machine only. It's not happing in my android studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 4. You should update from 4.1 to the latest android version.

Comment: You can try to change the hotkey of replacing files Ctrl+Shift+R , set something else. and then check again. I think it will be fixed after that.

Comment: So sorry, edited the proper short cut, its Alt+Shift+R while selecting a code block to create a method out of it